# Up to date example of static website deployed to CloudFront

Tags: aws-cdk

Does anyone know if there's an up to date example or tutorial for deploying a static website to CloudFront using the AWS CDK?

I'm also interested in using a Lambda@Edge to do some path rewriting, as described [here](https://read.acloud.guru/supercharging-a-static-site-with-lambda-edge-da5a1314238b#892c).

Last time I looked at this, it seemed there wasn't a way to specify a static destination bucket for S3 assets, so I started tracking [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/659) which appears to have been resolved.

I would appreciate any advice or documentation on best practices for this.

Comment: If you're only doing the path rewriting as described in that article, you don't really need the Lambda@Edge IMHO. The default S3 behavior already returns assets with a valid path and in other cases you can redirect to 'index.html', i.e. by setting `websiteErrorDocument: 'index.html'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an official example using the AWS CDK in Typescript: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/static-site/static-site.ts

The relevant part is in `static-site.ts`:

```
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'Zone', { domainName: props.domainName });
        const siteDomain = props.siteSubDomain + '.' + props.domainName;
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'Site', { value: 'https://' + siteDomain });

        // Content bucket
        const siteBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'SiteBucket', {
            bucketName: siteDomain,
            websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
            websiteErrorDocument: 'error.html',
            publicReadAccess: true,

            // The default removal policy is RETAIN, which means that cdk destroy will not attempt to delete
            // the new bucket, and it will remain in your account until manually deleted. By setting the policy to
            // DESTROY, cdk destroy will attempt to delete the bucket, but will error if the bucket is not empty.
            removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY, // NOT recommended for production code
        });
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'Bucket', { value: siteBucket.bucketName });

        // TLS certificate
        const certificateArn = new acm.DnsValidatedCertificate(this, 'SiteCertificate', {
            domainName: siteDomain,
            hostedZone: zone
        }).certificateArn;
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'Certificate', { value: certificateArn });

        // CloudFront distribution that provides HTTPS
        const distribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'SiteDistribution', {
            aliasConfiguration: {
                acmCertRef: certificateArn,
                names: [ siteDomain ],
                sslMethod: cloudfront.SSLMethod.SNI,
                securityPolicy: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_1_2016,
            },
            originConfigs: [
                {
                    s3OriginSource: {
                        s3BucketSource: siteBucket
                    },
                    behaviors : [ {isDefaultBehavior: true}],
                }
            ]
        });
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'DistributionId', { value: distribution.distributionId });

        // Route53 alias record for the CloudFront distribution
        new route53.ARecord(this, 'SiteAliasRecord', {
            recordName: siteDomain,
            target: route53.AddressRecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
            zone
        });

        // Deploy site contents to S3 bucket
        new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployWithInvalidation', {
            sources: [ s3deploy.Source.asset('./site-contents') ],
            destinationBucket: siteBucket,
            distribution,
            distributionPaths: ['/*'],
          });
```